# Why is hostname lookup in ssh returning a different result?

Tags: linux, ssh, host

I have one machine with two ips,

```
Something like this, (/etc/hosts)

10.204.65.18    blahdb01.us.oracle.com blahdb01
10.204.63.56    blah01.us.oracle.com   blah01
```

Now, whenever I do,

```
ssh blah01
```

It automatically connects to,

```
blahdb01
```

Now I wanna know where this behavior is getting populated. If I want to stop this... I want to map blah01 to blah01 only ... What can be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First check your `~/.ssh/config` file and see if you have any `Hostname` lines that are causing this.  Then, try using `dig` or `nslookup` on `blah01` and see if that shows anything interesting.

Note that `/etc/nsswitch.conf` can be used to change how the machine does name resolution so you should check that too.

Finally, a tool like `strace` can be used to examine how the program you are using is trying to open and read files to do name resolution.  For example:

```
strace -eopen,read -f -o /tmp/ssh-strace.txt ssh blah01
```

then look at `/tmp/ssh-strace.txt` and see if there's anything interesting in there about which files are being opened and read - that might provide a clue to what path is being followed.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) :) .. strace helped to resolve this. Actually all request id going through dns server (`/etc/resolv.conf`) which in turn has `CNAME` pointing to blahdb01... I am thinking of removing dns from the /etc/nsswitch.conf

Answer (score 0):

Check `/etc/resolv.conf` - its possible that you have a 'search' line which will automatically complete things using that.